# What's the best way for a Django app to get the current IP address of eth0

Tags: python, django

I've got a Django app that (for obscure reasons) needs to know the IP address of the server it's running on to present it back to the client. I can be pretty sure that the server will have `eth0` up and running, so really, I need the address of `eth0`.

What's the best way to get this? Ideally, this should be enumerated at uwsgi startup, and not necessarily every request. I thought about putting some code in `settings.py`, but think that might get run/enumerated on every request.

*edit* I should add that this is a debian linux server, running nginx and running a Django application within uwsgi.

Comment: The IP address of your local `eth0` interface might not be the same one that your clients see and might be unreachable from their side (e.g. it might be on a private network)

Comment: That's true generally, but in this specific case, the IP of eth0 is the IP that's relevant to the client.

Comment: What exactly is the setup.... Is it nginx on top of uwsgi on top of django (for instance)?

Comment: Yes, apologies, should have included in the question. Updated.

Comment: @growse so are you after the IP of the nginx server? (eg... the "outermost" part of the stack?) Or, where the uwsgis (master/slaves) are, or where one where the django app servers from... ?

Comment: I'm after the IP of the server that the `python` binary executing the Django application is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code that I use to get the public facing ip (on *nix systems):

```
# Hack to find machine NIC IP
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.connect(("8.8.4.4", 80))
MACHINE_IP = s.getsockname()[0]
s.close()
```

Comment: Any ideas on the best way to integrate that into Django, so it's run on application startup and the result stored somewhere?

Comment: You can put this code in `settings.py`. So it can be later used as `settings.MACHINE_IP`

Comment: I'll give that a go, thanks. My concern is that if this is evaluated on every request it could have a performance impact.

Comment: `settings.py` is not evaluated for each request, so you should be good to go.